# After contact enters a journey, how can i make sure the contact will receive an email once a year?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a journey with a data extension as entry criteria, which will be filled via an automation. After entering the journey the contact will receive an email. After this email i send, I want the contact to receive this email on annual bases. The entry criteria of this journey are too specific to let him join this same journey over and over again. So how can i make sure that after entering the journey and receiving the email, the contact will receive this same email once a year on the initial entry date?

Cheers

Comment: do you want it to be in bulk once a year, or have each send yearly at the initial entry date?

Comment: Best would be send it yearly at the initial entry date.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest adding an update activity to your current journey. This activity sets the current date for the subscriber (either on the contact record or in a data extension that is connected to the contact model), so you know the first time a send occurred. A second journey will be used for the yearly send then. The entry event of this new journey should be a date-based entry source analogous to the [anniversary campaign described in the journey builder best practices](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_bp_anniversary_campaigns.htm&type=5).

Another option that substitutes the second journey is an automation including a SQL-activity and an email send. The SQL-activity fetches all records, that have an anniversary on the current day and writes them to the data extension that is used for the send email activity.

**Further reading:**

- [Anniversary Campaigns](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_bp_anniversary_campaigns.htm&type=5)
- [Create a Date-Based Event](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_create_date_based_event.htm&type=5)
- [Update a Contact](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_update_a_contact.htm&type=5)

Comment: Hi Markus, thank you for your reply. We are using Salesforce as our master of record. Updating a date field which has a different purpose then being updated for this journey or adding a date field is not an option in this case unfortunately.

Comment: You can also update a data extension using the activity. The date based events can be used as long as the data extension is connected to the data model. Another option is fetching the records whose anniversary is on the current day via SQL and sending the email via automation studio.